# Launch "snappy" atom from terminal

Tags: command-line, snap, atom

Formerly, I was using atom installed from the Ubuntu official repos. I could easily open a project (folder) typing `atom .`

I recently have installed it using the snap package that Ubuntu provides. Everything looks fine, except for if I try to launch it as I used to do it I get the following error:

```
> $ atom .                                                         
No command 'atom' found, did you mean:
 Command 'atrm' from package 'at' (main)
 Command 'atop' from package 'atop' (universe)
 Command 'atoms' from package 'horae' (multiverse)
 Command 'atom4' from package 'atom4' (universe)
 Command 'atobm' from package 'x11-apps' (main)
zsh: command not found: atom
```

However, I can launch it normally from the unity launcher.

This is Ubuntu 16.04 and Unity as DE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may launch `atom` by the following command:

```
snap run atom
```

In order to launch it using the shorter command `atom`, you can set this alias:

```
alias atom='snap run atom'
```

and write it into your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file, so every new terminal instance has it automatically set.

Comment: Thank you!
In order to launch it using the shorter command `atom`,  you can set this alias: `alias atom='snap run atom'` and write it into your .bashrc or .zshrc file, so every new terminal instance has it automatically set.

Comment: @Akronix Edited that in!